# Write permissions on volume mount with security context fsgroup option

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to run a tomcat container in K8S with a non-root user, to do so I set User 'tomcat' with the appropriate permission in Docker Image. I have a startup script that creates a directory in /opt/var/logs (during container startup) and also starts tomcat service.

```
#steps in Dockerfile
#adding tomcat user and group and permission to /opt directory
addgroup tomcat -g 1001 && \
adduser -D -u 1001 -G tomcat tomcat && \
chown -R tomcat:tomcat /opt

#switch user
User tomcat
```

The pod runs fine in K8S when deployed using deployment without any volume mapped.

But I get a permission denied error (permission denied: creating directory /opt/var/logs/docker/) from the startup script, which fails to create a directory when I map the deployment with the persistent volume claim, even though I set the fsgroup as explained here, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/.

I have a persistent volume of type hostPath.

The deployment definition is as below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ms-tomcat
  namespace: ms-ns
  labels:
    app: tomcat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      securityContext:
          fsGroup: 2000
          runAsUser: 1001
          runAsGroup: 1001
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: docker-registry.test.com/tomcat:1.2
        volumeMounts:
        - name: logging-volume
          mountPath: /opt/var/logs/docker
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: test
      volumes:
      - name: logging-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nonroot-test-pvc
```

PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name:  nonroot-test-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: local-node-sc
  volumeName: nonroot-test-pv
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `fsGroup` to `1001` which is the `runAsGroup`.

When any volume mount in any path, by default the owner of the mounted directory is root. you can't change the owner of the mounted path in K8s world. But In k8S You have permission to set the group ID with FsGroup. With FsGroup you actually give the permission for a certain user group.

As your current user UID is `1001` and `GID` is `1001` so you need to give the permission for current `GID` `1001`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ms-tomcat
  namespace: ms-ns
  labels:
    app: tomcat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      securityContext:
          fsGroup: 1001 #<--- change here
          runAsUser: 1001
          runAsGroup: 1001
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: docker-registry.test.com/tomcat:1.2
        volumeMounts:
        - name: logging-volume
          mountPath: /opt/var/logs/docker
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: test
      volumes:
      - name: logging-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nonroot-test-pvc
```

Comment: Emon46 - that didn't help.

Comment: can you help me with sharing the pvc yaml?

Comment: Since the startup script that I have creates a folder in /opt/var/logs, giving permission to the /opt from init containers helping and solving the issue. But should have been resolved through fsgroup.

Comment: but i think the init container need to run as root user

Answer (score 1):

you need to run an initcontainer that will execute chmod 777 on the mounted volume to to be able to use the volume in a container with a non root user

this can be easily done by creating an init container from an alpine image

you can face this problem when trying to use longhorn as your storage class

like this:

```
spec:
  initContainers:
      - name: permission-init
        image: alpine:3.16.0
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - (chmod 777 /data)
        volumeMounts:
          - name: files
            mountPath: /data
```